# for loop code runs fine but it does not do what I want it to do

Tags: loops, logic

My objective is to roll a pair of dice 1000 times using the PairOfDice class which uses the Die class. While rolling it 1000 times, each time the PaidOfDice sum is equivalent to 7 I must count it until the loop terminates at 1000. So i've made a loop to counts to 1000 for 1000 rolls. I've look at the output and noticed that count increments by 1 sometimes when roller.roll() is not equal to 7. Here's my code.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ChidoriDiceRoller 
{
   private PairOfDice roller;
   private int count, sum;
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      PairOfDice roller = new PairOfDice();
      int count = 0;

      for(int i = 1; i <= 1000; i++)
      {
         roller.roll();
         System.out.println(i +"/"+ roller.roll() +"/"+ count);

            if (roller.roll() == 7)
            {
               count++;
               //System.out.println(roller.roll() +"/"+count );
            }

      }
   }
}
```

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
//********************************************************************
//  PairOfDice.java       Author: Lewis/Loftus
//
//  Solution to Programming Project 4.9 and 5.11
//********************************************************************

public class PairOfDice
{
   private Die die1, die2;

   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   //  Creates two six-sided Die objects, both with an initial
   //  face value of one.
   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   public PairOfDice()
   {
      die1 = new Die();
      die2 = new Die();
   }

   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   //  Rolls both dice and returns the combined result.
   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   public int roll()
   {
      return die1.roll() + die2.roll();
   }

   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   //  Returns the current combined dice total.
   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   public int getTotalFaceValue()
   {
      return die1.getFaceValue() + die2.getFaceValue();
   }

   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   //  Returns the current value of the first die.
   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   public int getDie1FaceValue()
   {
      return die1.getFaceValue();
   }

   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   //  Returns the current value of the second die.
   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   public int getDie2FaceValue()
   {
      return die2.getFaceValue();
   }

   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   //  Returns the string representation of this pair of dice.
   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   public String toString()
   {
      return "Die 1: " + die1.getFaceValue() + "   Die 2: " +
             die2.getFaceValue();
   }
}
```

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
//********************************************************************
//  Die.java       Author: Lewis/Loftus
//
//  Solution to Programming Project 5.11
//
//  Represents one die (singular of dice) with faces showing values
//  between 1 and the number of faces on the die.
//********************************************************************

public class Die
{
   private final int MAX = 6;  // maximum face value

   private int faceValue;  // current value showing on the die

   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   //  Constructor: sets the initial face value.
   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   public Die()
   {
      faceValue = 1;
   }

   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   //  Rolls the die and returns the result.
   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   public int roll()
   {
      faceValue = (int) (Math.random() * MAX) + 1;

      return faceValue;
   }

   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   //  Face value mutator.
   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   public void setFaceValue(int value)
   {
      faceValue = value;
   }

   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   //  Face value accessor.
   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   public int getFaceValue()
   {
      return faceValue;
   }

   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   //  Returns a string representation of this die.
   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   public String toString()
   {
      String result = Integer.toString(faceValue);

      return result;
   }
}
```

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
I cut out the first 900 rolls but here is an example of what i mean. it doesn't count right. where this is "i/roller.roll()/count" for i = number of rolls

```
900/10/142
901/3/142
902/10/143
903/9/143
904/9/143
905/10/143
906/4/143
907/9/144
908/6/144
909/11/144
910/10/144
911/6/144
912/4/144
913/8/144
914/7/145
915/7/145
916/6/145
917/6/145
918/9/145
919/7/145
920/10/145
921/8/145
922/12/145
923/6/145
924/5/145
925/7/145
926/5/146
927/7/146
928/6/146
929/11/146
930/5/146
931/10/146
932/12/146
933/6/146
934/4/146
935/6/146
936/5/146
937/7/146
938/2/146
939/8/146
940/2/146
941/3/146
942/8/146
943/11/147
944/9/147
945/5/147
946/11/147
947/9/147
948/5/147
949/9/147
950/9/147
951/5/147
952/6/147
953/6/147
954/7/147
955/6/147
956/8/147
957/4/147
958/9/147
959/8/147
960/7/147
961/6/147
962/8/147
963/3/147
964/11/147
965/4/147
966/6/147
967/7/147
968/10/147
969/4/147
970/10/147
971/6/147
972/7/147
973/10/147
974/6/147
975/10/147
976/8/147
977/9/148
978/8/148
979/9/148
980/3/148
981/11/148
982/10/148
983/10/148
984/11/148
985/7/148
986/6/148
987/6/148
988/10/148
989/7/148
990/10/148
991/9/148
992/4/148
993/4/148
994/9/148
995/7/148
996/11/148
997/9/149
998/8/149
999/5/149
1000/11/149
```

Comment: Example of the last 100 rolls in the code. as you can see count doesnt really count when roller.roll() == 7 i dont know why.

Answer (score 0):

Each time you call roller.roll(), it rolls the dice again.

You should store the result in a variable, such as

```
[...]
int result = roller.roll()
System.out.println(i +"/"+ result +"/"+ count);

if (result == 7)
{
    count++;
    //System.out.println(roller.roll() +"/"+count );
}
[...]
```

to avoid rolling more times than you intend.

Comment: I just changed the code to make sum =  roller.roll(); and put it in my statement but that still gives me faulty count numbers i dont know why

Comment: Did you use sum in both the print statement and the if statement? When I run the code like that it works properly.